# Parent child sql table show as table in php

Tags: php, sql, join, datatables, parent-child

I have table structure like this:

```
ID    Name     ParentId
-------------------------
1     Root      0
2     Business  1
3     Finance   2
4     Stock     3
5     Any       3
6     One       0
7     Two       6
```

Is there any way to get all relation in one line?

Like this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|ID        | NAME       |    ID     | NAME      | ID       | NAME    | ID     | NAME |
|----------|------------|-----------|-----------|----------|---------|--------|------|
| 1        | Root       | 2         | Business  | 3        | Finance | 4      | Stock|
| 1        | Root       | 2         | Business  | 3        | Finance | 4      | Any  |     
| 1        | One        | 6         | Two       |          |         |        |      |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your table has a name "htable" and as soon as there are up to FOUR (4) levels of hierarchy, it can be done like that using self join:

```
SELECT  level1.ID, level1.Name,
        level2.ID, level2.Name,
        level3.ID, level3.Name,
        level4.ID, level4.Name
FROM htable AS level1
LEFT JOIN htable AS level2 ON level1.ID = level2.ParentId
LEFT JOIN htable AS level3 ON level2.ID = level3.ParentId
LEFT JOIN htable AS level4 ON level3.ID = level4.ParentId;
```

Comment: It's not the right way.. I've got a table with NULLS, I don't really need that rows @Philip

Comment: I saw on your "answer" below what you want. Just add "WHERE level1.ParentId = 0" at the end.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT  level1.ID, level1.Name,
        level2.ID, level2.Name,
        level3.ID, level3.Name,
        level4.ID, level4.Name
FROM htable AS level1
LEFT JOIN htable AS level2 ON level1.ID = level2.ParentId
LEFT JOIN htable AS level3 ON level2.ID = level3.ParentId
LEFT JOIN htable AS level4 ON level3.ID = level4.ParentId;
```

This query returns unnecessary NULLS, I only need the red squared rows to print.

Image below.

[returned values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc6m6.png)

Comment: Just add "WHERE level1.ParentId = 0" at the end.